# Laravel 8 Jetstream Login Not Authenticating and Redirecting to Dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-forge, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel 8 with Jetstream. I am also using Envoyer and Forge.

In my local setup, I can register, login and reset password.  But in production, I can only register.  When I register, I get an email with a verification link that takes me back to the login screen, but when I enter my credentials, it seems as if it does a refresh and clears my login form. I know that it's hitting the database, because if I enter wrong credentials, I get a validation error.  I turned debug on, but there are no errors.  The logs `say No application encryption key has been specified.` but they are specified. I have restarted my server, cleared all caches--I am completely stumped.

I have a dozen Laravel apps running and this is the first time this has happened. Any ideas?

Comment: try php artisan clear  and php artisan view:clear and also php artisan key:generate.if still not working try to clear php artisan config:clear

Comment: I re-tried all the commands and still wont log me in.

Comment: Session value set in memory.  Tried different browsers.  Cleared browser cache.  Still same.

Comment: try once php artisan config:clear ,run php artisan key:generate php artisan config:cache

Comment: @JohnLobo Sorry if I sound harsh or bad, but do not post a lot of comments, post 1 comment with all the information you want to transmit, I see 8 comments where you had a 1v1 interaction and those had to be 4 comments... I am saying this because it is going to get threaded and we do not want that on SO when we want to help.

Comment: @matiaslauriti.i will take a note.thanks for letting me know :)